# Uniqueness of homogeneous equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Hi i am bit confused with the following problem:

$y^{''}(t)+p(t)y^{'}(t)+q(t)y(t)=0$ , where $p$ and $q$ are continuous functions.

Suppose that p is a odd and q is even (i.e., $p(-t)$=$-p(t)$, $q(-t)$=$q(t)$ for all t).

a) If $y$ is solution to the homogeneous equation on $[-a,a]$, show that $\tilde{y}$$(t)$=$y$$(-t)$ is also a solution.

I am not sure how to go about it, i thought of the characteristic equation as the equation is homogeneous but not sure what to do with it.

Any hint please?

Comment: Is $y$ a function of $t$, $x$, or both?

Comment: y a function of t

Comment: I guess then that so are $p$ and $q$. You should edit your post.

Comment: May be everything are functions of $t$ instead of $x$?

Comment: Well yes if you want, i was just defining odd and even

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose $y(t)$ is a solution of

$${{{d^2}} \over {d{t^2}}}y(t) + P(t){d \over {dt}}y(t) + Q(t) = 0\tag{1}$$

your assumption is

$$\eqalign{
  & P( - t) =  - P(t)  \cr 
  & Q( - t) = Q(t) \cr}\tag{2} $$

Now let us put $y(-t)$ into Eq.$(1)$ to get

$${{{d^2}} \over {d{t^2}}}y( - t) + P(t){d \over {dt}}y( - t) + Q(t)\tag{3}$$

Now just consider the change of variable $u=-t$ and use the chain rule to get

$$\eqalign{
  & {{{d^2}} \over {d{t^2}}}y( - t) = {{{d^2}} \over {d{u^2}}}y(u)  \cr 
  & {d \over {dt}}y( - t) =  - {d \over {du}}y(u) \cr} \tag{4}$$

Next, use $(3)$ and $(4)$ to get

$$\eqalign{
  & \,\,\,{{{d^2}} \over {d{u^2}}}y(u) - P( - u){d \over {du}}y(u) + Q( - u)  \cr 
  &  = {{{d^2}} \over {d{u^2}}}y(u) + P(u){d \over {du}}y(u) + Q(u)  \cr 
  &  = 0 \cr} \tag{5}$$

which completes the proof. :)

Comment: Thank you very much for the input, hmm did you mean change of variable u=-t ?

Comment: Yes indeed! I fixed that typo! :)